# Should std::atomic<int*>::load be doing a compare-and-swap loop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, atomic, compare-and-swap

**Summary**: I had expected that `std::atomic<int*>::load` with `std::memory_order_relaxed` would be close to the performance of just loading a pointer directly, at least when the loaded value rarely changes. I saw far worse performance for the atomic load than a normal load on Visual Studio C++ 2012, so I decided to investigate. It turns out that the atomic load is implemented as a [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) loop, which I suspect is not the fastest possible implementation.

**Question**: Is there some reason that `std::atomic<int*>::load` needs to do a compare-and-swap loop?

**Background**: I believe that MSVC++ 2012 is doing a compare-and-swap loop on atomic load of a pointer based on this test program:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
__declspec(noinline) T loadRelaxed(const std::atomic<T>& t) {
  return t.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

int main() {
  int i = 42;
  char c = 42;
  std::atomic<int*> ptr(&i);
  std::atomic<int> integer;
  std::atomic<char> character;
  std::cout
    << *loadRelaxed(ptr) << ' '
    << loadRelaxed(integer) << ' '
    << loadRelaxed(character) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I'm using a `__declspec(noinline)` function in order to isolate the assembly instructions related to the atomic load. I made a new MSVC++ 2012 project, added an x64 platform, selected the release configuration, ran the program in the debugger and looked at the disassembly. Turns out that both `std::atomic<char>` and `std::atomic<int>` parameters end up giving the same call to `loadRelaxed<int>` - this must be something the optimizer did. Here is the disassembly of the two loadRelaxed instantiations that get called:

**`loadRelaxed<int * __ptr64>`**

```
000000013F4B1790  prefetchw   [rcx]  
000000013F4B1793  mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
000000013F4B1796  mov         rdx,rax  
000000013F4B1799  lock cmpxchg qword ptr [rcx],rdx  
000000013F4B179E  jne         loadRelaxed<int * __ptr64>+6h (013F4B1796h)
```

**`loadRelaxed<int>`**

```
000000013F3F1940  prefetchw   [rcx]  
000000013F3F1943  mov         eax,dword ptr [rcx]  
000000013F3F1945  mov         edx,eax  
000000013F3F1947  lock cmpxchg dword ptr [rcx],edx  
000000013F3F194B  jne         loadRelaxed<int>+5h (013F3F1945h)
```

The instruction `lock cmpxchg` is atomic [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) and we see here that the code for atomically loading a `char`, an `int` or an `int*` is a compare-and-swap loop. I also built this code for 32-bit x86 and that implementation is still based on `lock cmpxchg`.

**Question**: Is there some reason that `std::atomic<int*>::load` needs to do a compare-and-swap loop?

Comment: I would also like to see why this kind of code is generated

Comment: @James I suspect that MS just has not yet had the time to implement this better. From my own implementation effort, it took only a tiny amount of code to make this faster, but it took a large amount of effort to understand in detail what that code was supposed to be doing and how that interacts with a given hardware platform. I have depended on material written by other people, but to be *really* sure that you did it right, I think it would be necessary to contact hardware vendors and to spend much time poring over the standard. Compare-and-swap is much easier to do and certainly correct.

Comment: See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770885/std-atomic-load-implementation-is-absurdly-slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that relaxed atomic loads require compare-and-swap. In the end this std::atomic implementation was not usable for my purpose, but I still wanted to have the interface, so I made my own std::atomic using MSVC's barrier intrinsics. This has better performance than the default `std::atomic` for my use case. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/broune/mathicgb/blob/master/src/mathicgb/Atomic.hpp). It's supposed to be implemented to the C++11 spec for all the orderings for load and store. Btw GCC 4.6 is not better in this regard. I don't know about GCC 4.7.