# VS2012 C++ generates questionable code for conditional move (cmov)

Tags: visual-c++, compilation, visual-studio-2012, x86-64

I have a ringbuffer that's written to by one producer and read by N consumers. As it's a ringbuffer it's ok for the index being written to by the producer to be less than the current minimum index of the consumers. The position of the producer and consumers is tracked by their own `Cursor`.

```
class Cursor
{
public:
    inline int64_t Get() const { return iValue; }
    inline void Set(int64_4 aNewValue)
    {
        ::InterlockedExchange64(&iValue, aNewValue);
    }

private:
    int64_t iValue;
};

//
// Returns the ringbuffer position of the furthest-behind Consumer
//
int64_t GetMinimum(const std::vector<Cursor*>& aCursors, int64_t aMinimum = INT64_MAX)
{
    for (auto c : aCursors)
    {
        int64_t next = c->Get();
        if (next < aMinimum)
        {
            aMinimum = next;
        } 
    }

    return aMinimum;
}
```

Looking at the generated assembly code I see:

```
    mov rax, 922337203685477580   // rax = INT64_MAX
    cmp rdx, rcx    // Is the vector empty?
    je  SHORT $LN36@GetMinimum
    npad    10
$LL21@GetMinimum:
    mov r8, QWORD PTR [rdx]    // r8 = c
    cmp QWORD PTR [r8+56], rax // compare result of c->Get() and aMinimum
    cmovl   rax, QWORD PTR [r8+56] // if it's less then aMinimum = result of c->Get()
    add rdx, 8                 // next vector element
    cmp rdx, rcx    // end of the vector?
    jne SHORT $LL21@GetMinimum
$LN36@GetMinimum:
    fatret  0   // beautiful friend, the end
```

I cannot see how the compiler thinks it's ok to read the value of `c->Get()`, compare it to the `aMinimum` and then conditionally move the RE-READ value of `c->Get()` into `aMinimum`. In my mind it's possible that this value has been changed between the `cmp` and `cmovl` instructions. If I'm correct then the following scenario is possible:

- `aMinimum` is currently set to 2
- `c->Get()` returns 1
- the `cmp` is done and the `less-than` flag is set
- another thread updates the value currently held by the current `c` to 3
- `cmovl` sets `aMinimum` to 3
- the Producer sees 3 and overwrites the data in position 2 of the ringbuffer even though it has not been processed yet.

Have I been looking at it for too long? Shouldn't it be something like:

```
mov rbx, QWORD PTR [r8+56]
cmp rbx, rax 
cmovl rax, rbx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using atomics or any kind of interthread sequencing operations around your access to `iValue` (presumably the same would be true of whatever might be modifying `iValue` on another thread, but we'll see that that doesn't matter), so the compiler is free to assume that it will remain unchanged between the two assembly lines of code. If another thread modifies `iValue` you have undefined behavior.

If your code is intended to be be threadsafe, then you'll need to use atomics, locks or some sequencing operation.

The C++11 standard formalizes this in section 1.10 "Multi-threaded executions and data races", which is not particularly light reading. I think the parts relevant to this example are:

Paragraph 10:

> An evaluation A is *dependency-ordered before* an evaluation B if
>
> - A performs a release operation on an atomic object M, and, in another thread, B performs a consume operation on M and reads a value written by any side effect in the release sequence headed by A, or
> - for some evaluation X, A is dependency-ordered before X and X carries a dependency to B.

If we say that evaluation A corresponds to the `Cursor::Get()` function and evaluation B would correspond to some unseen code that modifies `iValue`. Evaluation A (`Cursor::Get()`) performs no operation on an atomic object and isn't dependency ordered before anything else (so there's no "X" involved here).

And if we say that evaluation A corresponds to the code that modifies `iValue` and B corresponds to `Cursor::Get()`, the same conclusion can be drawn. So there is no "dependency-ordered before" relation between `Cursor::Get()` and the modifier of `iValue`.

Therefore, `Cursor::Get()` isn't dependency ordered before whatever might modify `iValue`.

Paragraph 11:

> An evaluation A inter-thread happens before an evaluation B if
>
> - A synchronizes with B, or
> - A is dependency-ordered before B, or
> - for some evaluation X
>
>   - A synchronizes with X and X is sequenced before B, or
>   - A is sequenced before X and X inter-thread happens before B, or
>   - A inter-thread happens before X and X inter-thread happens before B.

Again, none of those conditions is met, so there's no inter-thread happens before.

Paragraph 12

> An evaluation A happens before an evaluation B if:
>
> - A is sequenced before B, or
> - A inter-thread happens before B.

We've shown that neither operation "inter-thread happens before" the other. And the term "sequenced before" is defined in 1.9/13 "Program execution" as applying only to evaluations that occur on a single thread ("sequenced before" is C++11's replacement for the the old "sequence point" terminology). Since we're talking about operations on separate threads, A cannot be sequenced before B.

So at this point, we find that `Cursor::Get()` does not "happen before" an `iValue` modification that occurs on another thread (and vice-versa). Finally we get to the bottom line for this in paragraph 21:

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

So, if you want to use `Cursor::Get()` on one thread and something modifying `iValue` on another thread, you need to use atomics or some other sequencing operation (mutex or such) to avoid undefined behavior.

Note that according to the standard, `volatile` isn't enough to provide sequencing between threads.  Microsoft's compiler *may* provide some additional promises to `volatile` to support well-defined interthread behavior, but that support is configurable so my suggestion would be to avoid relying on `volatile` for new code.  Here's a bit of what MSDN has to say about this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/12a04hfd.aspx):

> **ISO Compliant**
>
> If you are familiar with the C# volatile keyword, or familiar with the behavior of volatile in earlier versions of Visual C++, be aware that the C++11 ISO Standard volatile keyword is different and is supported in Visual Studio when the /volatile:iso compiler option is specified. (For ARM, it's specified by default). The volatile keyword in C++11 ISO Standard code is to be used only for hardware access; do not use it for inter-thread communication. For inter-thread communication, use mechanisms such as std::atomic from the C++ Standard Template Library.
>
> **Microsoft Specific**
>
> When the /volatile:ms compiler option is used—by default when architectures other than ARM are targeted—the compiler generates extra code to maintain ordering among references to volatile objects in addition to maintaining ordering to references to other global objects. In particular:
>
> - A write to a volatile object (also known as volatile write) has Release semantics; that is, a reference to a global or static object that occurs before a write to a volatile object in the instruction sequence will occur before that volatile write in the compiled binary.
> - A read of a volatile object (also known as volatile read) has Acquire semantics; that is, a reference to a global or static object that occurs after a read of volatile memory in the instruction sequence will occur after that volatile read in the compiled binary.
>
> This enables volatile objects to be used for memory locks and releases in multithreaded applications.

Comment: Ok, I do use atomics to set the value (edited the code) and the volatile read generates the code I'd expect. What confuses me is that the assembly code I saw looks like what I'd expect to see if the access was volatile! Thanks for you lengthy reply. I'll have to pay more attention to std::atomic. I already am compiling with /volatile:iso

Comment: The code generated when std::atomic is used is also iffy IMO. Someone else brought it up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213113/should-stdatomicintload-be-doing-a-compare-and-swap-loop. The `prefetchw` instruction isn't even an Intel instruction: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/697740/amd-only-prefetchw-instruction-is-generated-in-x64-optimized-code