# Accessing C++11 std atomic without any memory ordering constraints

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-model, stdatomic

Various lock-free algorithms have no load or store ordering requirements in the fast-path. For example, in this work-stealing http://www.cs.rice.edu/~vs3/PDF/ppopp.09/p45-michael.pdf the steal operation requires an atomic compare-and-swap, but the frequent operations (put and take) specifically are designed to need no ordering constraints whatsoever. I've come across this sort of pattern in many other cases.

So why is there no way to access std atomic variables without enforcing memory constraints? While on x-86(-64) memory_order_relaxed doesn't insert any CPU barrier instructions, it prevents compiler reordering (at least from what I can see in the Visual C++ 2012 implementation), which still surely has a negative performance. Indeed, since the memory order is a run-time parameter, there's also the penalty of a branch incurred. In combination, that makes things even worse. Here's the code in the Visual C++ 2012 implementation that stores a uint32_t value into an atomic_uint32_t, after a switch statement determines that it's memory_order_relaxed (see xatomic.h):

```
_Compiler_barrier();
__asm
    {
    mov eax, _Value;
    mov edx, _Tgt;
    mov [edx], eax;
    }
_Compiler_barrier();
```

A load with memory_order_relaxed from it then ends up executing

```
_Value = _InterlockedOr((volatile long *)_Tgt, 0);
```

which is even worse as the _InterlockedOr intrinsic is a full CPU barrier (xatomic.h).

So, 1) why is non-memory ordered access not part of the std API, and 2) what's a work-around other than rolling one's own atomic API, other than an ugly reinterpret_cast of the atomic class to a non-atomic type and doing some compile-time checking of sizeof and offsetof?

(Note that I'm not talking about mixing atomic and non-atomic accesses, as I'm concerned with integral types whose normal load and store are already atomic on architectures I target.)

Comment: *"at least from what I can see in the Visual C++ 2012 implementation"* IIRC that implementation was [sub-optimal](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770885). Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13213113/420683

Comment: dyp, thanks for the comment. The _InterlockedOr for a load certainly seems an oversight on their part, but in terms of a proper implementaiton, wouldn't compiler reordering be still blocked, thus potentially preventing possible optimizations?

Comment: In VS2013, a relaxed `std::atomic<int>::store` on non-ARM (and in debug mode) is just a `*_Tgt = _Value;` and nothing more. Those compiler-barriers are unnecessary AFAIK. Relaxed memory ordering only guarantees atomic access to the data, and provides no inter-thread ordering.

Comment: That paper is very interesting, but to be clear: It does **not** eliminate all necessary memory orderings on the fast-path (also doesn't claim this), but only Store-Load barriers. Now for x86 those are the only kind you need because the rest are implicit and they are the most expensive barrier kind for all ISAs, but beware that on other ISAs you cannot use a normal load alone! No idea how to do this for the x86 special case either though - apart from inline assembly (gcc allows syntax to make this efficient and allow the optimizer to work on it, don't think MSVC does and it's not c++11 anyhow)

Comment: Thanks. I'll upgrade to VS2013, but in the meantime, as I cannot check the source, does the store/load still cast to volatile on non-ARM?

Comment: Yes, it uses an `__iso_volatile_store32` for ARM.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for x86 specifically.